# How to force `.andExpect(jsonPath()` to return Long/long instead int for int number for jackson parser

Tags: json, jackson, spring-test, spring-rest

I have a simple test to my RestController. I expect that `$[1].parent_id`returns Long as an object and not integer primitive. It will return Long if `parent_id` is in a long number range and > integer number range (such as : 2147483650L).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TransactionServiceControllerTest {

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    // I copy this from my RestController class
    this.transactions = Arrays.asList(
            new Transaction(100d, "car", null),
            new Transaction(100d, "table", 12L)
     );
}

@Test
public void readSingleBookmark() throws Exception {
   mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/transaction/"))
   .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType)) // ok
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2))) // ok
   //omitted
   andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].parent_id",is(this.transactions.get(1).getParentId())));
} //assertion fail

Expected: is <12L>
but: was <12>
```

Result from another test :

```
Expected: is <12L>
but: was <2147483650L> //return Long instead int
```

this is my JacksonConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //supposed to be this is the magic trick but it seems not..
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS);


        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT);
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

And my POJO

```
public class Transaction {

private double ammount;

private String type;

private Long parentId;

public Transaction(Double ammount, String type, Long parentId) {
  //omitted
}
//setter and getter omitted
}
```

MyRestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("transaction")
public class TransactionServiceController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
List<Transaction> getTransaction() {
    return
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Transaction(100d, "car", null),
                    new Transaction(100d, "table", 12L)
            );
    }
}
```

And Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly note that if you find one of the answers to your question acceptable, feel free to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you want to.

Comment: I am really sorry that today (after 1 year) I just realise that I hit the wrong button. I thought accepting answer were ```up button```. But it is a ```check button ``` which has been explained thoroughly in ```Stackoverflow new user welcoming how to```. many thank to SamBrenner to friendly (almost neglected) reminder.

Comment: No worries. Cheers! ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update

- Spring Framework 4.3.3 and 5.0.0 added first-class support for explicit conversions for **request** content for use with `MockRestServiceServer`.

  - See [SPR-14498](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14498) for details.
- Spring Framework 4.3.15 and 5.0.5 will add first-class support for explicit conversions for **response** content for use with `MockMvc`.

  - See [SPR-16587](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16587) for details.

---

### Original Answer

One option (which I haven not personally verified) would be to try a different [`JsonProvider`](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#jsonprovider-spi). This can be set via `com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.setDefaults(Defaults)`.

If you are sure that the `Long` can always be safely narrowed to an `int`, you could use the following:

```
andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].parent_id",is(this.transactions.get(1).getParentId().intValue())));
```

And the only other option is to write a custom `Matcher` that converts the incoming `Integer` to a `Long` before performing the actual matching.

Comment: this method for explicit conversion with MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath() is no longer available. I cannot find it in docs either.

Comment: The explicit `targetType` variant was added to `JsonPathRequestMatchers` but not to `JsonPathResultMatchers`. I'll see to it that we fix that ASAP!

Comment: FYI: the following JIRA issue will address this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16587

Comment: I have revised my answer accordingly. See the _updated_ "Update" section.

Comment: great! Thank you for the quick response :)

Answer (score 24):

Since Spring 5.2 you can provide type as a third argument of `jsonPath()` method:

```
public static <T> ResultMatcher jsonPath(String expression, Matcher<T> matcher, Class<T> targetType)
```

So in this case it will be:

```
andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].parent_id",is(this.transactions.get(1).getParentId()), Long.class));
```

Source:
[Spring Javadoc API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#jsonPath-java.lang.String-org.hamcrest.Matcher-java.lang.Class-)